# Finding largest prime factor of a composite number in c

Tags: c, prime-factoring

I am accepting a composite number as an input. I want to print all its factors and also the largest prime factor of that number. I have written the following code. It is working perfectly ok till the number 51. But if any number greater than 51 is inputted, wrong output is shown. how can I correct my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
 int i, j, b=2, c;
 printf("\nEnter a composite number: ");
 scanf("%d", &c);
 printf("Factors: ");

 for(i=1; i<=c/2; i++)
 {
  if(c%i==0)
  {
   printf("%d ", i);
   for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
   {
    if(i%j > 0)
    {
     b = i;
    }
    if(b%3==0)
     b = 3;
    else if(b%2==0)
     b = 2;
    else if(b%5==0)
     b = 5;
   }
  }
 }
 printf("%d\nLargest prime factor: %d\n", c, b);
}
```

Comment: which part of the output is incorrect? The factors or the largest prime factor?

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind checking if `b` is a factor of 3,2,or 5?

Comment: @Willfulwizrd: Suppose if I enter any number greater than 51, say if I input 52. Ideally it should display 13 as the largest prime factor but it is displaying 2 as the answer.

Comment: @Jacob: Actually the code I have written in the 2nd for loop is not validating 3 as prime number. And if I edit that for loop, it doesnt consider 5 to be a prime number which gives wrong output. So I have checked for those 3 values of b.

Comment: That behavior is happening because it gets to a number divisible by 2, 3, or 5 that is greater than the largest prime factor (it tests 26 for 52). In fact, that is the same reason that it was not working previously on the values you mentioned.

Comment: @Jacob: so after checking the value of b for these 3 numbers, the code runs perfect for any input less than 52. But any number greater than 52 and even 52 are giving wrong output.

Comment: Actually, after rereading that section, it seems to me that `b` is being set to a bunch of numbers that are not factors of `c` and are not necessarily prime. Can you explain the logic of the inner for loop?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469882

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469882/printing-the-largest-prime-factor-of-a-composite-number-in-c ?

Comment: Now I am inclined to think this and it's dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469882/printing-the-largest-prime-factor-of-a-composite-number-in-c are both homework.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit of a spoiler, so if you want to solve this yourself, don't read this yet :). I'll try to provide hints in order of succession, so you can read each hint in order, and if you need more hints, move to the next hint, etc.

**Hint #1:**
If divisor is a divisor of n, then n / divisor is also a divisor of n. For example, 100 / 2 = 50 with remainder 0, so 2 is a divisor of 100.  But this also means that 50 is a divisor of 100.

**Hint #2**
Given Hint #1, what this means is that we can loop from i = 2 to i*i <= n when checking for prime factors. For example, if we are checking the number 100, then we only have to loop to 10 (10*10 is <= 100) because by using hint #1, we will get all the factors.  That is:

```
100 / 2 = 50, so 2 and 50 are factors
100 / 5 = 20, so 5 and 20 are factors
100 / 10 = 10, so 10 is a factor
```

**Hint #3**
Since we only care about prime factors for n, it's sufficient to just find the first factor of n, call it divisor, and then we can recursively find the other factors for n / divisor. We can use a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_eratosthenes) approach and mark off the factors as we find them.

**Hint #4**
Sample solution in `C`:

```
bool factors[100000];

void getprimefactors(int n) {
  // 0 and 1 are not prime
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) return;

  // find smallest number >= 2 that is a divisor of n (it will be a prime number)
  int divisor = 0;
  for(int i = 2; i*i <= n; ++i) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      divisor = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (divisor == 0) {
    // we didn't find a divisor, so n is prime
    factors[n] = true;
    return;
  }

  // we found a divisor
  factors[divisor] = true;
  getprimefactors(n / divisor);
}

int main() {
  memset(factors,false,sizeof factors);
  int f = 1234;
  getprimefactors(f);
  int largest;
  printf("prime factors for %d:\n",f);
  for(int i = 2; i <= f/2; ++i) {
    if (factors[i]) {
      printf("%d\n",i);
      largest = i;
    }
  }
  printf("largest prime factor is %d\n",largest);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
---------- Capture Output ----------
> "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c c:\temp\temp.exe
prime factors for 1234:
2
617
largest prime factor is 617
> Terminated with exit code 0.
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! It really worked. Thak you once again for the great help.

Answer (score 3):

I presume you're doing this to learn, so I hope you don't mind a hint.

I'd start by stepping through your algorithm on a number that fails.  Does this show you where the error is?

Comment: Ofcourse, I'll be pleased to receive your hint. If I'm interpreting the hint correctly, you suggests that I must run the program line by line? Actually, I did want to do it but I'm running c on a Linux platform and I'm new to Linux. SO I'm not able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Please feel free to let me know if I have mis-interpreted your hint.

Comment: user417316, compile your code with the -g compiler flag and run it with gdb <program name>.  Use step or next as described here: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_38.html.  You can peek at your variables in gdb using C-like syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much !! I'll definitely try this and get back asap.

Comment: Either that, or pencil and paper!  Donald Knuth recommends that method in his book _Fundamental Algorithms_.

Answer (score 2):

You need to recode so that your code finds all the prime numbers of a given number, instead of just calculating for the prime numbers 2,3, and 5.  In other words, your code can only work with the number you are calculating is a prime number or is a multiple of 2, 3, or 5.  But 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 are also prime numbers--so your code should simply work by finding all factors of a particular number and return the largest factor that is not further divisible.

Comment: Actually the code that I have written above does take into account 7, 11, 13, 17 and 19 also as prime numbers and even displays them correctly if any one of them is the largest prime factor for any composite number less than equal to 51. It's only creating a problem 52 onwards.

Comment: So I'm not able to figure out how to code for all numbers atleast upto 100.

Answer (score 0):

Really, this is very slow for all but the smallest numbers (below, say, 100,000).  Try finding just the prime factors of the number:

```
#include <cmath>

void addfactor(int n) {
    printf ("%d\n", n);
}

int main()
{
    int d;
    int s;
    int c = 1234567;
    while (!(c&1)) {
        addfactor(2);
        c >>= 1;
    }
    while (c%3 == 0) {
        addfactor(3);
        c /= 3;
    }
    s = (int)sqrt(c + 0.5);
    for (d = 5; d <= s;) {
        while (c % d == 0) {
            addfactor(d);
            c /= d;
            s = (int)sqrt(c + 0.5);
        }
        d += 2;
        while (c % d == 0) {
            addfactor(d);
            c /= d;
            s = (int)sqrt(c + 0.5);
        }
        d += 4;
    }
    if (c > 1)
        addfactor(c);
    return 0;
}
```

where addfactor is some kind of macro that adds the factor to a list of prime factors.  Once you have these, you can construct a list of all the factors of the number.

This is dramatically faster than the other code snippets posted here.  For a random input like 10597959011, my code would take something like 2000 bit operations plus 1000 more to re-constitute the divisors, while the others would take billions of operations.  It's the difference between 'instant' and a minute in that case.

Comment: When I try your code with 1234, it lists 2 and 5 as prime factors, when actually the prime factors are 2 and 617.

Comment: Oops, incremented c instead of d... that's what I get for not testing.

Answer (score 0):

Simplification to dcp's answer(in an iterative way):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void factorize_and_print(unsigned long number) {
  unsigned long factor;
  for(factor = 2; number > 1; factor++) {
    while(number % factor == 0) {
      number = number / factor;
      printf("%lu\n",factor);
    }
  }
}

/* example main */
int main(int argc,char** argv) {
  if(argc >= 2) {
    long number = atol(argv[1]);
    factorize_and_print(number);
  } else {
    printf("Usage: %s <number>%<number> is unsigned long", argv[0]);
  }
}
```

Note: There is a number parsing bug here that is not getting the number in argv correctly.